# How to do a pivot - group by - pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have this dataset:

```
DatasetMonthYear 
Month   Year    Id     Person_Id          Name 
----------------------------------------------------- 
1       2007    855    5987456            John Slow 
2       2007    850    5987456            John Slow 
1       2007    254    5987456            John Slow 
2       2008    987    5987456            John Slow 
1       2007    456    5454543            Mary Jane 
1       2007    454    5454543            Mary Jane 
2       2008    554    5454543            Mary Jane
```

i need to group or count one row by month, Id and Person_Id, but counting that occurrence as one,  so i make this query.

```
select pv.Person_Id,  pv.Name,  pv.Year, 
    (CASE [1] when 0 THEN 0 else 1 end) as January,
    (CASE [2] when 0 THEN 0 else 1 end) as Februry 
from DatasetMonthYear as P 
pivot ( count(Id) for 
Month in ([1], [2]) ) as pv
```

the result is this dataset:

```
Person_Id   Name         Year  January    February
------------------------------------------------------ 
5987456     John Snow    2007     1          0 
5987456     John Snow    2007     0          1 
5987456     John Snow    2008     0          1 
5454543     Mary Jane    2007     1          0 
5454543     Mary Jane    2008     0          1
```

now i need the sum of each month by one Person_Id on a year, so i try add another pivot as follows.

```
 select Person_Id,Name, [2007], [2008] 
     from (select pv.Person_Id,pv.Name, Year, (CASE [1] when 0 THEN 0 else 1 end) as January,
                (CASE [2] when 0 THEN 0 else 1 end) as February
from DatasetMonthYear as P 
pivot ( count(Id) for 
Month in ([1], [2]) ) as pv) as resulset 
      pivot( sum() for Year in ([2007],[2008]) ) as apv
```

and here is where i am stuck. i need a grouping by Person_ID, a sum of each month (January + Februry+...+etc) and pivot in years

Result i want :

```
 2007    2008    Person_Id   Name 
   2       1     5987456     John Snow 
   1       1     5454543     Mary Jane
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the output that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need two Pivots here, you can get your desired result using one Pivot, see below

```
select * from
(
  select DISTINCT Person_Id, name, Year, Month From DatasetMonthYear
) Src
Pivot
(
  Count(Month) For Year In ([2007],[2008])
) Pvt
```

[SQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f699/3)

Comment: i noticed that my monthly view was counting Ids instead of counting month